# Python, how to get a count of specific value in a group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (df) containing 3 columns

```
df.columns = ['date','color','tag']
```

The "tag" column contains values "A", "B", "C"
I want to create a new column "l3A" showing me the count of last 3 occurrences of a specific value, let's say 'A' in "Tag" column, but grouped by color.

When I use the following code it works, but just for the total number of occurrences within a total range of rows.

```
df['l3A'] = df.query('tag == "A"').tag.count()
```

How can I get the number of the occurrence of a specific value within groups  df.groupby('color') and for the last 3 rows?

Comment: It’s not very clear to me what you’re looking for. How can you want a count if it’s the last 3 occurrences? That’s always going to be 3 no? Can you maybe provide an example of input and output of what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need count last 3 values `tag` per groups of colors if match `A` use custom function in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for `sum` last 3 values of new column `new` filled by boolean mask from compare by `A`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=8),
                 'color':['red','red','red','red','blue','green','green','green'],
                 'tag':['A','D','D','D','A','A','A','D']})
  
#sorting if necessary
# df = df.sort_values(['color','date'])

f = lambda x: x.tail(3).sum()
df['l3A'] = df.assign(new= df['tag'].eq("A")).groupby('color')['new'].transform(f)
print (df)
        date  color tag  l3A
0 2020-01-01    red   A    0
1 2020-01-02    red   D    0
2 2020-01-03    red   D    0
3 2020-01-04    red   D    0
4 2020-01-05   blue   A    1
5 2020-01-06  green   A    2
6 2020-01-07  green   A    2
7 2020-01-08  green   D    2
```